Please check my proof that $[1,\infty)$ is complete for the usual metric
I claim that the metric space $([1, +\infty), d_1)$ where $d_1$ is the usual Euclidean metric is complete.
I want to ask about the validity of my argument for this claim. So here goes:
Proof of claim
We recall that a metric space $(X,d)$ is complete if every Cauchy sequence in X converges to a limit in X.
So let $(x_n)_{n \ge1}$ be a Cauchy Sequence in $[1,+\infty)$, so in particular:
For all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $N_1 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n, m \ge N_1$ $\Rightarrow$ $|x_n - x_m|< \epsilon$, where each $x_n, x_m \in [1, +\infty)$.
So let $(x_n)_{n \ge1}$ be the above sequence. Fix $\epsilon > 0$. Choose $N = N_1$. So for all $n\ge1$, we yield $|x_n - x| < \epsilon$ where $x:= x_m \in [1, +\infty)$.
Therefore we see that every Cauchy Sequence in $[1, +\infty) $ converges to a limit in $[1, +\infty)$. So the metric space in question is complete.
$\blacksquare$
Remark
I think the second to last line is almost unnecessary as it's repeating the line prior.
I hope this question is useful for other trying to prove a metric space is complete.
Many thanks.

The penultimate sentence is not justified.

Really? Clearly, can't I just set any of the x_m to be the limit? If not, how can you justifying it?

Do you know the definition of the limit of a sequence? For instance, what is the limit of the sequence $x_n=1/n$ and is it equal to some $x_n$? And my proof would be completely different from yours. I would use the fact that $[1,\infty)$ is a closed subset of the real line. Does your textbook cover open and closed subsets?

Yes, the definition of the limit of a sequence is: If there is $x \in X$ satisfying for every $\epsilon > 0$, there is $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n \ge N$ we have $d(x_n, x) < \epsilon$. The limit in your $x_n$ is 0 and no it does not equal to some $x_n$

Now you see why you cannot simply set "any of the $x_m$ to be the limit."

Please tell us which specific step you are unsure of in your proof per the solution-verification tag, as we are NOT a Check-My-Homework-For-Me site

I have another idea: Let $(x_n)$ be a Cauchy sequence in $([1, +\infty), d_1)$, then it is a Cauchy sequence in $(R,d_1)$. Since, $(R,d_1)$ is complete, then the limit of the Cauchy sequence lies in some x in R. Since $[1, +\infty)$ is a closed subset of R, then by defn of closed subset, the cauchy sequence have to converge within the subset. So the metric space is complete.

As it was pointed out in the comments, your solution is not correct. Here is how a possible solution could go (this is very similar to the idea given in the comments, but even more straight-forward since we take advantage of the order structure of the reals):
Consider a Cauchy sequence $(a_n)_n$ where each $a_n\geq1$. Since the reals are complete, $a_n$ has a limit on $\mathbb R$; let's call it $a$. We then have, by monotonicity of the limit operator
$$a=\lim a_n\geq\lim 1=1$$
And so $a\in[1,\infty)$, and so $a_n$ converges on $[1,\infty)$, which implies $[1,\infty)$ is complete
